# Convert 12 hour time to 24 hour using Joda time

Tags: android, datetime, jodatime, joda-convert

I am getting this error
Invalid format: "09:30 PM" is malformed at " PM"

```
LocalTime start = new LocalTime();
LocalTime end = new LocalTime();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("hh:mm a");
start = formatter.parseLocalTime(from.toLowerCase());
end = formatter.parseLocalTime(to.toLowerCase());
```

Comment: try use `HH` instead of `hh`

Comment: `hh` should be correct. It represents a "halfday hour". `HH` means hour of day (= 0-23)

Comment: Try to set English locale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Pattern is incorrect. Please use the following:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter= DateTimeFormat.forPattern("hh:mm aa");
```

Edit: Here is a link to the [Documentation for DateTimeFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html).

Comment: could you add a link to the documentation, where the pattern is explained ?